# GetManifestResourceStream() returning NULL in debugger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, embedded-resource

I am embedding some XML resource in my application and it works loading the XSD file but not for the XML file. This is how I load the XSD file.

```
    private static XmlSchema LoadXsdResource(string folder, string xsdName)
    {
        string filename = string.Format("Namespace.{0}.{1}.xsd", folder, xsdName);
        using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(filename))
        {
            return XmlSchema.Read(stream, (o, e) =>
            {
                log.Warn(string.Format("Napaka pri parsanju XSD sheme {0}: {1}: {2}", e.Severity, e.Message, filename));
            });
        }
    }
```

Somewhere else I load the XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Resources.Oddaja.xml"));
```

This also works, but *only* if I run the compiled assembly. When I run it with the debugger, I get a `NullReferenceException` coming from `GetManifestResourceStream()`.

So I messed it up with the namespaces, right? No, I checked and double checked. The namespaces are correct, and if they weren't I would be getting an exception in the running assembly. (I log whenever an exception happens) I also double checked with .NET Reflector to see that the resources are really there with the names I expect.

I also triple checked and made sure that the `Build Action` is set to `Embedded Resource` but nothing worked. I remind you it *works fine* when I run the exe outside the debugger and I can event print the XML. When run with the debugger though, it returns null and the program crashes.

What could cause `GetManifestResourceStream()` to return null only when debugging?

Comment: What is the calling assembly when you're running in the debugger? (I would pull that out as a local variable, and check that first.)

Comment: Yes Jon I just thought about that. Since I am foolishly calling my code from `Main()` the calling assembly is the debugger. I wanted `GetExecutingAssembly()`... Its always these little things that cost me the most time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` is indeed the problem.  When you are debugging, your code is being called by the Visual Studio Hosting process, `yourapp.vshost.exe`.  Which of course does not contain your resource.

A workaround would be Project + Properties, Debug tab, untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process option".  But of course the real fix is to pay more attention to the location of the code vs the location of the resource, making `GetExecutingAssembly()` the most likely correct choice.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was I was running my code from `Main()`. The documentation of [`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) states:

> Returns the Assembly of the method that invoked the currently executing method.

The `Assembly` that invoked my `Main()` method is of course the debugger. The debugger has no resources that I want and it crashed. The `LoadXsdResource()` method works because the calling assembly is mine and has the resources I want.

What I wanted is [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx):

> Gets the assembly that **contains the code that is currently executing.**

If I would have put my code in a class this wouldn't have happened. I guess I paid the tax for being stupid.

Answer (score -1):

It returns null when its file name path is wrong. It becomes complete path likes this
 System.IO.Stream s = b.GetManifestResourceStream("TestApp.XML.test.xml");

```
Nanespace.FileFolderName.xmlfilename.xml
TestingEnvironmentNamespace.Test.test.xml
```

above examples shows best way how to map perfect path.